# contract factory function causes contract to exceed size limit

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, openzeppelin, hardhat, optimization

I'm writing a smart contract where one of the functions deploys a payment splitter contract that inherits from OZ PaymentSplitter.sol. I'm doing something like:

```
function splitterFactory(address[] memory payees, uint256[] memory shares_) private {
splitterContract _splitterContract = new splitterContract(payees, shares_);
}
```

when this function is marked as internal or private, it compiles just fine. If it's public or external, my smart contract is too big and does not compile.
using `hardhat-contract-sizer` i can see that by changing this single function from internal to public adds over **10 kb** to my final, most derived contract

my question is, is this normal? is there any tricks to fix this? does cloning or proxies take up less space? should I just deploy a contract factory separately on its own? I tried using solidity optimizer to no success.

Thanks!
Nolan

Answer (score 0):

maybe try the --optimize flag, along with --optimize-runs=25.
this usually gets rid of the size errors for me.

Comment: thanks, I tried the optimizer, but ill try 25 specifically. I specify it in the hardhat.config file, do I need to add the flag every time I compile?

Comment: I don't know much about hardhat, but I think if you do it in the config file, it'll automatically do it every time.